# How to enable hot refresh of freemarker templates in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm looking for enabling **hot refresh of ftl files** on spring boot framework, so that changes on ftl files need not require application restart.
I had tried following settings through application.properties,

```
spring.freemarker.cache=false
spring.freemarker.template_update_delay=0
```

but yet still not getting to it.

*How can I enable it through application properties?*

thanks!

Comment: What `TemplateLoader` is that setup using? (Put it differently, where do you keep your templates and how do you replace them?)

Comment: My template folder lies within classpath (resources folder). Should I move it out of my package?

Comment: If you enable debug logging for the `freemarker.cache` log category, you will probably find that FM in fact does re-check if the resource was changed. Then either you replace them on a location that's not used by the "deployed" app., or the Java `ClassLoader` in use does some kind of caching or reports wrong last modification times. So, can you make your own code to see the changes? Load the resource directly via the `URL` returned by `Class.getResource` to see. Also, then check if `java.net.URLConnection.getLastModified()` returns the correct value.

Comment: BTW, is `cache=false` a Spring-specific extension? Because FreeMarker has no such setting. You should not disable caching anyway.

Comment: Are your template files in the `WEB-INF` dir?

Comment: In spring boot we place template files in templates folder inside src/main/resources

Answer (score 4):

I'm using SpringBoot with maven and I have the same problem. I just discovered that the templates are in target/classes/templates so after modifying a template you have to rebuild the project to reinstall the template in classes. This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can reload freemarker templates without restarting the application.
It is simple and does not need spring boot devtools.

Just find the location of your ftlh template files on disk add this to your application.yml:

```
spring:
    freemarker:
        # replace with your template path:
        template-loader-path: file:///C:/Users/David/example/src/main/resources/templates
        cache: false
        prefer-file-system-access: true
```

You can find more about application.properties for templating here:
[Spring Boot Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.application-properties.templating)

Also remember that you should use profiles and put your development settings in a separate properties file:
[Spring Boot Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles)

Tested with Spring Boot 2.7.2

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion didn't help me...

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ 2022.2.1 Ultimate Edition
For me in the Spring Boot Run Configuration was not set "Update resources" by default. It was set to do nothing. With that setting it worked for me.
I'm also using the Spring DevTools.
[Spring Boot Run Configuration Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqQE0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I use springloaded as recommended in the documentation.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-hot-swapping

Answer (score 1):

Even i faced the same problem. Tried opening in incognito mode. Tried setting browser cache to false. Nothing worked.

Now i copy and paste whatever changes i make to the original ftl to the target folder's ftls

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Build Project,
[build button location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywR29.png)
or you can set build automatically,
spring doc says that IDE auto update your classpath when you change your template,
but it doesn't,so you should do it by yourself.
in eclipse or intelliJ,click
Build -> Build Project

hope help you

official link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-property-defaults
20.2 Automatic Restart
Triggering a restart

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 steps.

1. Import devtools:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

2. Disable cache:

```yaml
spring:
  freemarker:
    cache: false
```

3. Build project autmatically

[image: Build project autmatically]

4. Idea IDE menu **Help** -> **Find Action**, Select `Registry`, Set `compiler.automake.trigger.delay` to `5` (seconds)

[image: Set time t]

After that, the IDE will trigger reload every `5` seconds.

From: [Hot reload Spring Boot Freemarker and Thymeleaf template on Idea IDE](https://www.awaimai.com/en/3054.html)